# Configure an autoreply for a public folder

Tags: exchange-2003

I would like to configure an auto reply on a public folder in exchange 2003.

Any hints and tips, links etc will be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do so by creating a rule for that public folder.

- In outlook, right click on the public folder, click on properties
- On the General tab click on the Folder Assistant Button, then add rule.
- Define the rule for replying, then check the reply with option and then click the template button to define what should be sent.

Your account will need to have the "Send As" permission for this public folder for you to do this.

Comment: I also made sure that the public folder was mail enabled, and set the required email address using the exchange system manager. And also, I had to make sure that OOR and automatic replies had been enabled in exchange too. I can't reboot yet, because this is a production machine, but we'll find out soon enough!